# Facebook like button - how to prevent activity stream from getting into the user's wall?

Tags: facebook-like, javascript-framework

Can someone please help me out as to how I can completely prevent the user's activity stream from posting back into their wall after they liked a linked? Because, I really find that to be annoying. Afterall, mine is an application that needs to be integrated into an image gallery viewer serving more than 7.5K photos each with its own like button.

If this seems impossible, is there a way to specifically set an image as thumbnail, description, etc as is with the cases of feed and send buttons?

Because, my application is purely dynamic in nature built out of 100% Javascript where more than 80% of its contents are generated by using Ajax calls under a static single URL.
As a result, the like button activity stream always end up pulling the wrong image and descriptions than desired(but this is not so for feed and send buttons),
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

No, you won't have control over not sending items to peoples activity feeds when they click like, unless your domain gets blocked for spam.  You would need to create a dynamic url or hashbang url for each independent image and when those images are requested the page hosting it would need to have the proper open graph meta tags sets for thumbnail image, description, etc. Then for each like button in the gallery, you would need to set the href property to this url.